# arrow function inside parentheses {} about react context

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions, react-context

In the tutorial of React context, I saw this code :

```
<MyContext.Consumer>
  {value => /* render something based on the context value */}
</MyContext.Consumer>
```

Then I get so confused, `value => /* render something based on the context value */` this part like `value => <h1>Hello, {value}</h1>` is a function right? Why we put a function here instead of the result of this function here? Like

```
<MyContext.Consumer>
      {<h1>Hello, {value}</h1>}
 </MyContext.Consumer>
```

In other function components we do things like:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.title}</h1>;
}
```

We put a final value kind of like the result of a function inside the {} right? But why we just put a function in the Context.Consumer instead of the result of the function? And how and when does this function get executed?
or why we don't write it like:

```
 <MyContext.Consumer>
     {(value =><h1>Hello, {value}</h1>)()}
 </MyContext.Consumer>
```

?
Thank you so much!

Comment: All your questions mentioned in the docs you are referring to, "function as a child" pattern, render props, and links for related info. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `<MyContext.Consumer>` is actually a component itself and it has to pass the `context` somehow to your child component. That's exactly why you pass it a function:

```
{value => /* render something based on the context value */}
```

`value` here is the context and the body of the function uses this context to return a `ReactNode`(or in other words your desired representation/component). This technique is called [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html). `<MyContext.Consumer>` will receive the function you pass it as a property named `children` and will call it inside its logic with the most current version of the context to render your desired component.

Somewhere inside `MyContext.Consumer`:

```
[this.]props.children(context);
```

which will actually resolve to a `ReactNode`, as already noted.

In your case, if you have:

```
<MyContext.Consumer>
    {<h1>Hello, {value}</h1>}
</MyContext.Consumer>
```

where is this `value` coming from?

---

**So, to recap:**

Let's say we have the following consumer and it holds a value for context of `Harry`:

```
<MyContext.Consumer>
     {context => <h1>Hello, {context}</h1>}
</MyContext.Consumer>
```

The function `context => <h1>Hello, {context}</h1>` will be passed to the `MyContext.Consumer` component. The consumer component will call it by passing to it the most current value of the context(in our case it is `Harry`) and then **return the result**. In the end, it will be like you simply have `return <h1>Hello, Harry</h1>`. That simple.

The function can actually contain other components itself. For example:

```
<MyContext.Consumer>
     {context => <Component2 contextValue={context} />}
</MyContext.Consumer>
```

will render the `Component2` component with the context passed to it as a property `contextValue`.

It's easier to wrap your head around it if you just consider your components as simple functions receiving parameters that they depend on(which is actually exactly how things work). Same goes for the `Consumer` component. It's whole purpose is to receive your component(a function) and pass to it the current context so it can render the proper output and return the result.

Note that this usage is related to functional components only and in the case you're not utilizing **react hooks**.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! I need to learn more about render props! So when we write: <MyContext.Consumer>
  {value => <h1>Hello, {value}</h1>}
</MyContext.Consumer> When will this function get called? It's called automatically?Why  we don't write it like : <MyContext.Consumer>
  {(value => <h1>Hello, {value}</h1>)()}
</MyContext.Consumer>? Also, we can receive this value variable because of this Consumer method right?

Comment: @Ying Yes, the function will be called automatically by the `Consumer` Component. Check the edit I've posted to the answer.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much @zhulien! I was so confused and thought it's a result tag <h1> we put inside the Consumer, but it's actually a function we pass to this consumer Component then it returns we something! Really thank you a lot for this detailed explanation!!! I hope I could be good at React like you one day! :D